# Omit namespace prefix when creating XML using SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following code

```
$base = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><realestates:office xmlns:realestates="http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/offer/realestates/1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></realestates:office>';

$objXml = new \SimpleXMLElement($base);
$objXml->addChild('title', 'Alles Toller');
$strXml = $objXml->asXML();
```

`$strXml` would now be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<realestates:office xmlns:realestates="http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/offer/realestates/1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    
<realestates:title>Alles Toller</realestates:title>
</realestates:office>
```

What I want is to not have the `realestates:` prefix in `<title>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<realestates:office xmlns:realestates="http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/offer/realestates/1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    
<title>Alles Toller</title>
</realestates:office>
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: While I can well imagine some code is expecting that output, note that the `<title>` element with no prefix is technically not in any XML namespace, even though other parts of the document use namespaces. In other words, you're saying "some parts of this document have a standardised meaning, but this bit is just thrown in there". It's possible that SimpleXML is quite right in assuming that the `<title>` element should actually be in the same namespace as the containing `<office>`.

Comment: @IMSoP: yes I think the parser that parses my output is quite rubbish. It also expects the sub nodes in a specific order - it was thinking that does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in using `DOMDocument`:

```
 $objXml = new \DOMDocument( "1.0", "UTF-8" );
 $objRoot = $objXml->createElement('realestates:office');
 $objXml->appendChild($objRoot);
 $objXml->createAttributeNS('http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/offer/realestates/1.0', 'realestates:office');
 $objXml->createAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:dummy');
 $objTitle = $objXml->createElement('title', 'Alles Toll');
 $objRoot->appendChild($objTitle);
 $strXml = $objXml->saveXML();
```

The second parameter of `createAttributeNS()` is a bit strange - only the namespace is not enough, it looks like I have to also add an element name.

Comment: `createAttributeNS` is only creating those `xmlns` attributes as a side-effect; what you are actually asking it to create is the attributes `realestates:office=""` and `xlink:dummy=""`, but in doing so the document has to declare which namespace goes with which prefix. Instead, use [createElementNS](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php) for your root element, e.g. `->createElementNS('http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/offer/realestates/1.0', 'realestates:office')`. Since the `xlink` namespace is never used, you don't need to declare it with `xmlns:xlink`.